# how to reference the quantity value when onchange is called in JSX component

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

This seems like it should be simple, but I'm a little lost in the context of React.  Any help would be much appreciated!

I am trying to use a quantity selector component (written by someone else), and onChange i want to reference the new value of the quantity in the callback, but when i use this.value it doesn't seem to work as shown below (i get a type error undefined in console).

Is there some other way to reference the "new" numerical value of the quantity dropdown?

```html
<QuantitySelector value = {props.itemCartQty}   onChange = {() => props.updateItemQty(props.item, this.value)}
     />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is this.value in your example, my guess is selected value. if thats the case, you can pass the event and get the selected value. Can you try the following code and see if it works for you.

```
updateItemQty(item, event){
var val = event.target.value;
.....
}
```

```html
<QuantitySelector value = {props.itemCartQty}   onChange = {(event) => props.updateItemQty(props.item, event)}
     />
```

Comment: actually your answer ended up working for me - thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the value from the `onChange` method like

```
<QuantitySelector value = {props.itemCartQty}   onChange = {(value) => props.updateItemQty(props.item, value)}
     />
```

Here `onChange` by default receives the updated value returned from the `QuantitySelector` component and passes it on the the `updateItemQty` method

Comment: Thanks Shubham!  You're a life saver!  I owe you a drink next time I'm in Bangalore haha